Why does Phantom block developers from using Solana?
Are you aware that Phantom blocks new projects on Solana by marking them as malicious sites, even when these projects have no harmful code, functions, or intentions?
There are no guidelines provided to avoid these markings; decisions seem to be made without explanation. It seems like every new project is automatically flagged. Why should new developers interested in integrating Solana into their projects be hindered in such an arbitrary manner?
If Phantom wants to filter out harmful sites, they should establish clear guidelines, or at the very least, examine the code or functions of each site. It’s disappointing to consider Solana as the mainnet for our project with such an indiscriminate approach by this wallet provider.
We all agree on blocking and removing harmful sites from our ecosystem, but that doesn’t justify a blanket approach to all new projects without guidelines.
https://github.com/phantom/blocklist
